# Same SciPy.linalg.eigh() eigenvalues are not equal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am using Python 2.7, NumPy 1.6.2 and SciPy 0.16.0 to calculate the following.

I have created a Hadamard matrix. Then I have created outer products from the 0,2,4-th vectors of the matrix and added them and made the diagonal 0. Then I have computed the eigenvalues using SciPy.linalg.eigh(). It is degenerate. First two eigenvalues are same, i.e., -3. But when I use Python to check it says they are not same. The code is given below.

```
from scipy import linalg as sp
import numpy
from numpy import linalg as np

def get_outer_product(vector):
    length = len(vector)

    outer_product = [[0 for x in range(length)] for x in range(length)]

    for i in range(0, length):
        for j in range(0, length):
            if i == j:
                outer_product[i][j] = 0
                continue
            outer_product[i][j] = vector[i] * vector[j]
    return outer_product

def test():
    hadamard_matrix = sp.hadamard(8)
    sum_of_outer_products = [map(sum, zip(*t)) for t in zip(get_outer_product(hadamard_matrix[0]), get_outer_product(hadamard_matrix[2]))]
    sum_of_outer_products = [map(sum, zip(*t)) for t in zip(sum_of_outer_products, get_outer_product(hadamard_matrix[4]))]

    e_vals, e_vecs = sp.eigh(sum_of_outer_products)
    print str(e_vals[0]) + " == " + str(e_vals[0]) + "?"
    print e_vals[0] == e_vals[1]
```

The output is:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import scipytest
>>> scipytest.test()
-3.0 == -3.0?
False
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print the actual values of the array and the types.  It isn't returning a complex type or something right?  Are you sure you're comparing two floats?

Answer (score 2):

[Floating point problem](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

When working with floats, always be careful with equal operator and remember that there might be precision problems and [use safe comparison](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
print str(e_vals[0]) + " == " + str(e_vals[0]) + "?"
print e_vals[0] == e_vals[1]
print numpy.isclose(e_vals[0], e_vals[1])
```

By the way, it returned true in both cases on my machine:

```
-3.0 == -3.0?
True
True
```

Comment: I am using NumPy 1.6.2.

Comment: @OmarShehab then you either update your library or you can implement your own version of `isclose()`, which just checks whether one floating point is approximately equal to another floating point especially seeing that documentation explains how `isclose` is implemented: `absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))`

Comment: I cannot upgrade NumPy because of other dependencies.  Do you have any idea why the output of print e_vals[0] == e_vals[1] is different at your end?

Comment: @OmarShehab these are just guesses, but `eig*` is using some numerical convergence algorithm and it does not always converge to absolutely the same point (may be this is -3.000000000000000018) and due to floating point inaccuracy the two numbers are not the same. It is actually good that you have noticed it now, and not in the middle of a way bigger project. I suggest never to use floating point equal operator and implement your own version of equality for floating points.

Comment: Does it mean that the eig() function has been modified in your version?

Comment: @OmarShehab I highly doubt that there were any changes to `eig` function from 1.6.2 to 1.7 version. It may be just converged exactly to -3. But even in this case I would not use the `e_vals[0] == e_vals[1]` code and will still use isclose or my own isclose implementation.